what happen if a do git pull after the commits references has changed in the remote repository?
let's say I have a branch called X, I create a lot of commits in this branch, then i push them to the remote repository. a friend to me in the same team checkout my branch and then pull all the changes, after that i noticed that i need to merge main into my branch X, so I did a rebase instead so all the commits change their reference, and i did a push -hard to the remote branch, my question is when my friend will do a git pull on his side what will happen?
I want to understand what will happen, what git will do internally ?

What will happen is called a mess.... to git those are unrelated commits..... so you are merging a different branch that is bringing over mostly the same thing.... but for every line where there is a difference (say, new work on your side... or your coworker's side), you will get a conflict.... and so on.... it's hell. Rule of thumb: do not rewrite history of branches that other people are already using. For a feature branch where you are the sole developer, it's of to rebase and stuff. But if that work is already being used by other people, it's a mess if you rebase

The rebased branch (the one now in the remote repository) and the original branch (the one in your friend's local repository) are two different branches. When he does git pull, the rebased one is fetched and then merged into the original one. The code could be still okay, but the history will be a nightmare. Do not rewrite any published branch. If you have to do so, inform all users of this big change and give instructions on how to deal with it.
